# If I add a sprite onto a jframe my background dissapears

Tags: java, swing

I'm trying to make a 2d side scrolling game. I have been able to display the background but as soon as I add a sprite the only thing displayed on the frame is the sprite. (Sorry if this is a simple mistake but I am new to java)

**Here is my main class**

```
package com.projectelrond.main;

import javax.swing.JFrame;

import com.projectelrond.Sprites.Ranger;

public class Main {

public int WIDTH = 160, HEIGHT = WIDTH/12 *9, SCALE = 3;

public boolean running = false;

BackGround bg = new BackGround();

JFrame f = new JFrame("name");

public static void main(String[] args) {
    new Main();

}

public Main() {

    f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    f.setSize(WIDTH * SCALE, HEIGHT * SCALE);
    f.setResizable(false);

    f.add(new BackGround());
    f.add(new Ranger());
    f.setVisible(true);

    running = true;

    run();
}

public void run() {
    while (running) {
        //handles in game events NPCs, Traps etc.
    }
    }

}
```

**My Background class**

```
    package com.projectelrond.main;

import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.JPanel;


public class BackGround extends JPanel {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public BufferedImage Bg;

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.drawImage(Bg, 0, 0, null);
    }

    public BackGround() {

        try {
            Bg = ImageIO.read(new File("src/Images/BG.png"));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }


    }
```

**and last but not least the sprite that I am trying to add**

```
    package com.projectelrond.Sprites;

import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Ranger extends JPanel{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public BufferedImage RangerIm;

    public Ranger() {
        try {
            RangerIm = ImageIO.read(new File("src/Images/Sprites/Ranger.png"));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.drawImage(RangerIm, 0, 0, null);
    }

}
```

Thanks for all the help and if there are any tips that you wish to share they will be much obliged.

Comment: `RangerIm = ImageIO.read(new File("src/Images/Sprites/Ranger.png"));` should be `RangerIm = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource("/Images/Sprites/Ranger.png"));` otherwise you will have issues once the application is built and deployed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
g.drawImage(RangerIm, 0, 0, null);
```

You are drawing the image at its actual size. There is no need to do custom painting for this. You would do custom painting if you want to scale the image.

Instead you can just use a `JLabel` with an `ImageIcon`:

```
BufferedImage rangerIm = ImageIO.read(new File("src/Images/Sprites/Ranger.png"));
JLabel ranger = new JLabel( new ImageIcon(rangerIm) );
ranger.setSize( ranger.getPreferredSize() );

BufferedImage backgroundIm = Bg = ImageIO.read(new File("src/Images/BG.png"));
JLabel background = new JLabel( new ImageIcon(rangerIm) );

background.add( ranger );
f.add(background, BorderLayout.CENTER);

f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
f.setResizable(false);
f.pack();
f.setVisible(true);
```

Now the ranger is added to the background which is added to the frame. Also, you need to add the components to the frame BEFORE the frame is visible(). The pack() method will make the frame the size of the background image.

Comment: Thank you it has worked I think I have messed up what you have told me to do but it has worked none the less

Comment: I'm wonering if you know how I could then move the ranger that I have added because if you do know it will save me a lot of searching (and frustration) trying to get it to move. Thank you in advance

Comment: You use the setLocation(...) method of the ranger label.